# VB.NET WebClient Windows Phone 7

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, webclient

i would like to know how i can get a page source code using vb.net webclient for windows phone 7.

I found a C# example but i need a vb.net example.

Thanks!

C# (The code i found on internet)

```
public void GetFeed()

{

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.slpg.org/syndication.axd"));

}



void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)

{

    string data = e.Result;

    // do something with the feed here

}
```

VB.Net (C# to VB website output)

```
Public Sub GetFeed()


    Dim client As New WebClient()

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += New DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf client_DownloadStringCompleted)

    client.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://www.slpg.org/syndication.axd"))

End Sub



Private Sub client_DownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)


    Dim data As String = e.Result

    ' do something with the feed here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the C# example through a C#-to-VB conversion utility such as [Code Translator](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/).

It's probably also a good idea to post the sample you found--maybe someone will be willing to translate it for you.